# How to generate random id inside using firebase cloud functions?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to achieve like below image :

[image]

I want to generate this **`SomeRandomId`** using firebase cloud functions when there is new node created in database .

I had done something like this before which generates **randomIds** at `otherdetails` key-value pair which is working fine  and it is implemented as below .

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.addUniqueCode = 
functions.database.ref('/Users/{userId}/').onCreate((snapshot , 
                                        context ) => {
  const code = makeid(6);

  var userdata = snapshot.val();

  console.log(code);

  return snapshot.ref.update({ otherdetails : code});

});

function makeid(length) {
   var result           = '';
   var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
   var charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
   result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 
                                     charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
}

//console.log(makeid(6));
```

Comment: What is exactly created under `/Users/{userId}/` that triggers the Cloud Function with `functions.database.ref('/Users/{userId}/').onCreate(..)`? It is not clear why you need to use a Cloud Function to create a sub-node at the location that triggers the Cloud Function. Why don't you directly write this sub-node under `/Users/{userId}/`?

Comment: What's the problem you're having with this code?

Comment: Usually people use `push()` to generate a new random ID for insertion into the database. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#push()

Comment: Without knowing what problem you're having, it's hard to help. In addition to using `.push()` like Doug suggested... I've used [this](https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/3596a30bd69384624c11) before to generate my own IDs when I had to do some manual data entry.